# How to return a queryset as a JSON response in Django RESTFramework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to return a queryset as a JSON response in DRF but I always get a TypeError Object Not JSON serializable.

I have tried different methods but none of them worked. I have tried to use the JSONRenderer class and I have also tried to serialize a single object using SentSerializer. But nothing seems to solve the issue. I have just started learning DRF so it is a little confusing to me and really don't understand how serializers work and I am not sure if I have written them correctly or using them correctly.

```
# models
...
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Sentence(models.Model):
    sent = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sent_correct = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='sentences')

# serializers
...
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # Tuple of serialized model fields (see link [2])
        fields = ( "id", "username", "password", )

class SentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    sent = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    sent_correct = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    author = UserSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Sentence
        fields = (
            'sent', 'sent_correct', 'author'
        )

# views
...
class SentCreateAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = SentSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        ss = Sentence.objects.filter(author=request.user)[0:1]
        ss = list(ss)
        print("sentences " + str(ss))
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        vd = serializer.validated_data
        sent_str = vd['sent']
        s = Sentence(sent=sent_str, sent_correct=sent_str)
        s.author = request.user
        print(vd)
        print(request.user)
        s.save()
        sent = nlp(sent_str)
        tokens = [t.text for t in sent] # this list returns successfully

        return Response(
            {   'sent': sent_str,
                'sent_correct': sent_str,
                'tokens': tokens,
                'ss': ss, # this list throws TypeError},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Jakub Maślanka answered my question on Facebook in Django Python Web Framework group. I had to serialize the queryset like this:

```
# views.py 
...

return Response(
            {   'sent': sent_str,
                'sent_correct': sent_str,
                'tokens': tokens,
                'ss': SentSerializer(ss, many=True).data},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

ss -> dict

Why dont you use generics.ListAPIView.
It has get_query_set method
You just need to override that method by your own query set
Less code is better -> class based and framework